# show branch/version in to end user

Tags: git

Is there a way to include the branch/commit id in the source, so it changes automatically?

in rcs there is the $Id:$ tags, which gets expanded, and can be used as text strings:

```
$VERS = '$Id: prog.php,v 1.8 2016/01/07 14:14:48 root Exp root $';
```

and the Log:

```
/*
* $Log: pos.php,v $
* Revision 1.8  2016/01/07 14:14:48  root
* Beep for opening drawer
*
* Revision 1.2.1.1  2011/12/23 09:06:16  root
* Log
*
*/
```

I'd like the enduser to be able to see the version/build etc info.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such way in git, the existing `$Id` in git will give you only the version of the current file not the whole repository.

And there is no equivalent of `$Log$` either.

Answer (score 0):

If it is not possible, as krzyk say, then I'll make a script to

```
git log -1 | formatLogPhp.awk > untracked_file.txt
```

untracked_file.txt could be

```
<?php
$_GIT_commit="76a80d0308f1fca6685cf87f9c210d6d67ba6171";
$_GIT_Author="Leif Neland <leif@my.dom>";
$_GIT_date=  "Fri Jun 24 13:13:24 2016 +0200";
$_GIT_log = "Initial checkin";
?>
```

then

```
<?php
require_once("untracked_file.txt");

...
echo "Welcome to mygloriousProgram version ".$_GIT_date";
```